# What is the function of a variable in a for loop conditional place?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a function that converts a list to an array.

```
function listToArray(list) {
    let arr = [];

    for (let node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
        arr.push(node.value);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

What's confusing to me is the node variable in the for loop. This bolded node: (let node = list; **node**; node = node.rest). How that bolded "node" works? What it is used for?

Comment: Like *any other expression there* it's evaluated for truthiness and the loop ends when it's false-y (presumably when `node.rest` is null or undefined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement in a `for` loop declaration is the condition under which the loop should be continued. Compare to the (hopefully familiar) construct:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  //            ^^^^^
}
```

In the above code, as long as `i < 5` is true, the loop will continue.

Similarly, in your code, as long as the `node` variable is truthy, the loop will continue. As soon as the `node` *stops* being truthy (due to the `node = node.rest` done at the end of an iteration), the loop will stop.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
function listToArray(list) {
    let arr = [];
    let node = list;
    while (node) {
      arr.push(node.value);
      node = node.rest;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: More specifically, the end of a linked list is indicated by setting `node.next = null`, and `null` is falsey while all objects are truthy.